# Issue trying to parse JSON serialized in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization

I am trying to send data from C# to JS. I am serializing it this way:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mydata mydata = new Mydata();
        mydata.name = "john";
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(mydata);
        Context.Response.Write(json);
    }
```

And in JS side I am doing it:

```
 page_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (page_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(page_request.responseText));
            }
        }
    }
```

It's raising the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON"

My responseText is:

```
{"name":"john"}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./SaveMinimum.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="aWjLtFUtylw6y57ZUALh7nrMIi/DnQX9NMokkMybnU3A5NV7mFW+00LcRuAJMPXWebf4w6HiyjI+7iXZoGyVB5Scq1g=" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="EF9FB8B6" />
</div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For sure the problem is the HTML right below the JSON data. Any idea on how to supress it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should not be trying to use a page to send data. [Web methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services#creating-ajax-enabled-web-services) or handlers would be more appropriate.

Comment: try context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to set a Content-Type as json:

```
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Context.Response.Write(json);
    Context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did the trick but with a small change: Context.Response.Write(json);

Comment: ooh yes is json, sorry

Comment: I'd like to add that I specially loved this solution because I don't have to use a whole new implementation (webmethod); instead I can use regular page implementation. :-)

Comment: @YanKleber a System.Web.UI.Page implements IHttpHandler but adds a lot of baggage that you don't need. It may be easiest for you (marginally) but IMO it is poor practice to create something that goes through the page lifecycle for no reason.